# Gradle build prints extraneous output

Tags: gradle

I have the following basic *build.gradle* script:

```
task count << {
   4.times { 
      print "$it-" 
   }
}
```

When I run it in quiet mode, it intermittently prints extraneous text, like the phrase *0% CONFIGURING* or *0% EXECUTING*:

```
C:\gradle-test>gradle -q count
0-1-2-3-------> 0% CONFIGURING [0s]
C:\gradle-test>gradle -q count
0-1-2-3-
C:\gradle-test>gradle -q count
0-1-2-3-------> 0% EXECUTING [0s]
```

Why does this extra text print arbitrarily and what does it mean?

Comment: What is your gradle version ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This text like  `0% EXECUTING` is called the **Status Bar** which is displayed when Gradle is run in Rich console mode (default mode if Gradle build process is attached to a console), see more information in the documentation here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#rich_console

> Why does this extra text print arbitrarily

Because in your example , this is a very simple build script which is executed so fast that "sometimes" the Status Bar has not had time to be displayed before build is finished (this is my interpretation, and I reproduced for example when calling task `clean` on very simple projects)

**EDIT**:  this *status bar* will be displayed even in "quiet" mode. if you want to disable it, you can configure the "plain text" console mode with Gradle commandline option `--console=plain`

Comment: Thanks for the insight, @M.Ricciuti!

Comment: Just to clarify, @M.Ricciuti - if the documentation you link to is correct, the default mode appears to be "auto", unless I'm missing something?

Comment: yes it's correct, mode `auto` appears to be the default mode. I updated my answer,